# How to force a subclass to make a constructor?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

So, I have a superclass with a constructor:

```
public Asset(InputStream input) throws Exception {
    load(input);
}
protected Asset() {}
```

The second constructor is so that I can make a constructor in the subclass that does everything via the arguments given to it, instead of loading the asset from an external source, however, I also want the subclass to make a constructor that uses super(InputStream).

So, the question is, how can I force a subclass to make a constructor using super(InputStream), but also allow a subclass to make a constructor without that?

Comment: You cannot enforce that, and why would you need to - why should a superclass put such a limitation on its subclasses?

Comment: I want to because I want to make sure that I can either programmatically create an asset, or load an asset. The asset class itself is abstract, with subclasses like ImageAsset, ModelAsset, etc...

Comment: Please read about the factory pattern and builder pattern for a better solution to your issue.

Comment: yeah, I have used the factory pattern in the past, to me it just leads to unorganized classes, but I can see that it could be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the super-class to **lack** a default constructor. For example:

```
public class Super{
    public Super(SomeParameter x) {

    }
}
```

Then, in the subclass you will be **forced** to provide *at least* a constructor, with one parameter of the `SomeParameter` type:

```
public class Sub extends Super {
    public Sub(SomeParameter x) {
        super(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: right, and I have that, but then I also want to be able to create a constructor in the subclass WITHOUT calling a superconstructor.

Comment: @MrabEzreb with or without some variable/param?

Comment: You can't, simply because when instantiating the subclass, some of the constructors of the super class will be called. Explicitly or not. This is just the way objects are created in java - the super class is part of the subclasses definition and therefore the superclass ctor is called, before anything else.

Comment: alright then, I guess it's fine, thanks a lot, cant say that this was an answer quite yet :|

Comment: What you are asking for is not possible in java. Super class constructor must be invoked before sub class constructor.

Comment: Unless you make a 'dummy' constructor with a param that you wont use. and also in super that constructor wont do anything.  (so 2 constructors needed)